# Assertion failure _state.get() error in MongoDB during mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2, mongodump, mongorestore

I would like to say i am newbie in mongodb,today i have tried to restore dump file .I am getting the `Assertion failure _state.get()` during `mongorestore` dump in my mongod and process has stuck at that time. 
The mongodb environment is as follows:

```
Mongodb version is - 3.2.16-11-g1abb660
O.S - Windows 7 Enterprise 32-bit
mongodb is running in Domain account.
```

As i am sending the below `restore` dump log from my `mongod`

```
2017-10-11T12:40:22.994+0300 I -        [conn11] Assertion failure _state.get() < 0 C:\data\mci\89fbcdee7b6a486969190f06feaabe28\src\src\mongo/util/concurrency/rwlock.h 204
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\log.cpp(136)                                                  mongo::logContext+0xba
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(137)                                          mongo::verifyFailed+0x17e
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\mmap_windows.cpp(164)                           mongo::MemoryMappedFile::close+0x5a
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\mmap_windows.cpp(340)                           mongo::MemoryMappedFile::map+0x800
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\durable_mapped_file.cpp(261)                    mongo::DurableMappedFile::create+0x137
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\data_file.cpp(175)                              mongo::DataFile::open+0x167
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\mmap_v1_extent_manager.cpp(241)                 mongo::MmapV1ExtentManager::_addAFile+0x175
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\mmap_v1_extent_manager.cpp(393)                 mongo::MmapV1ExtentManager::_createExtent+0x8d
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\mmap_v1_extent_manager.cpp(497)                 mongo::MmapV1ExtentManager::allocateExtent+0x93
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\record_store_v1_base.cpp(528)                   mongo::RecordStoreV1Base::increaseStorageSize+0x2f
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.693+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\record_store_v1_simple.cpp(169)                 mongo::SimpleRecordStoreV1::allocRecord+0x28a
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\record_store_v1_base.cpp(353)                   mongo::RecordStoreV1Base::_insertRecord+0x8d
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\mmap_v1\record_store_v1_base.cpp(342)                   mongo::RecordStoreV1Base::insertRecord+0x145
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\record_store.h(379)                                     mongo::RecordStore::insertRecords+0x6a
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\catalog\collection.cpp(443)                                     mongo::Collection::_insertDocuments+0x20b
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\catalog\collection.cpp(361)                                     mongo::Collection::insertDocuments+0x248
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\catalog\collection.cpp(378)                                     mongo::Collection::insertDocument+0x73
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(1048)                mongo::insertOne+0x155
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(784)                 mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::insertMany+0x15b
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(846)                 mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::execInserts+0x247
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(686)                 mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::bulkExecute+0x6f
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(332)                 mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::executeBatch+0x2d4
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\write_commands.cpp(146)                 mongo::WriteCmd::run+0x157
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\dbcommands.cpp(1468)                                            mongo::Command::run+0x791
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\dbcommands.cpp(1340)                                            mongo::Command::execCommand+0x75f
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\commands.cpp(505)                                               mongo::runCommands+0x282
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.694+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(263)                                               mongo::receivedCommand+0x287
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.695+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(520)                                               mongo::assembleResponse+0x51d
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.695+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(180)                                                     mongo::`anonymous namespace'::MyMessageHandler::process+0x93
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.695+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\net\message_server_port.cpp(229)                              mongo::PortMessageServer::handleIncomingMsg+0x3f8
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.698+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(187)  std::_LaunchPad<std::_Bind<1,void *,void * (__cdecl*const)(void *),nspr::Thr
    ead *> >::_Go+0x10
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.699+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdcpp\thr\threadcall.cpp(28)                           _Call_func+0x17
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.699+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\threadex.c(376)                                 _callthreadstartex+0x1b
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.699+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\threadex.c(354)                                 _threadstartex+0x7c
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.703+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] kernel32.dll                                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.703+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11] ntdll.dll                                                                                      RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xef
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.704+0300 I CONTROL  [conn11]
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.705+0300 I CONTROL  [conn13] MapViewOfFileEx for C:\data\db\citibike.2 at address 00000000 failed with errno:8 Not enough storage is available to process this command. (file size is 268435456) in Memo
    ryMappedFile::map
    2017-10-11T12:40:23.708+0300 I -        [conn13] Assertion failure _state.get() < 0 C:\data\mci\89fbcdee7b6a486969190f06feaabe28\src\src\mongo/util/concurrency/rwlock.h 204
```

I am also attaching the `mongorestore` dump error & also `mongod` screen shot

mongorestore dump error
[image]

mongod error
[image]

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Your picture links does not work. Did you see this in your output `ailed with errno:8 Not enough storage is available to process this command`?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide, I have just edited. Could you check you again? Please. May be the site maintenance or else. I also don't know the exact reason. Just i trim the picture size and again upload that.

Comment: As it is pointed out, you run out of disk space!

Comment: @JJussi, Approx 200 GB disk space is available .

Comment: At all your disks? System and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a 32-bit O/S the total addressable file size for MongoDB's MMAP storage engine is [limited to ~2GB of data including indexes (and journal, if enabled)](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/32-bit-limitations). Given the [32-bit limitations for memory-mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), journaling is off by default on 32-bit MongoDB builds as otherwise the data limit would be halved. This is not a recommended configuration for any important data: unclean shutdown is very likely to result in data integrity issues.

The WiredTiger storage engine, which is the default storage engine in MongoDB 3.2 and newer, only supports 64-bit operating systems.

From the log provided it appears that you have exceeded the maximum storage size that can be memory-mapped for a 32-bit server:

> 2017-10-11T12:40:23.705+0300 I CONTROL  [conn13] MapViewOfFileEx for C:\data\db\citibike.2 at address 00000000 failed with errno:8 Not enough storage is available to process this command. (file size is 268435456) in MemoryMappedFile::map

If your database is too large for the limitations of MMAP on a 32-bit O/S, you will have to either do a partial restore or upgrade to a 64-bit environment.

Note: 32-bit server builds were officially [deprecated as of MongoDB 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/#platform-support) and are no longer available for MongoDB 3.4+.

Comment: You are absolutely right. As even i also installed 64 bit of MongoDB (ver 3.4) in my laptop and able to restore my "mongodump" there. So, i am going to accept you answer.